# Can't find PInvoke DLL 'Resco.KeyboardPro.Native.dll

Tags: windows, mobile

I use Resco's UI controls for my Windows Mobile application developed in VS2008. When I try to execute the project, upon loading my app crashes with the message of,

> Can't find PInvoke DLL 'Resco.KeyboardPro.Native.dll

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

make sure that Resco.KeyboardPro.Native.dll is deployed on your device. In VS08 You need to add the DLL as a resource or a project asset. If as an asset, you need to set Build Action property of the DLL to "Content" and Property 'Copy to Output Directory' needs to be set to "Copy if newer" or "Copy always". Mark as answer if this solves your issue. Good Luck.